# How to compare two classifiers performance using `scipy.stats.ttest_rel`?

Tags: classification, t-test, accuracy, model-evaluation, scipy

I want to compare two classifier performance using T-Test. Using the [`scipy.stats.ttest_rel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_rel.html):

```
a = clf1.perdict(X)
b = clf2.predict(X)
s, p = scipy.stats.ttest_rel(a, b)
```

Is it a correct way to compare classifiers' performance? and what's the interpretation of `s` and `p` values?

Comment: You might be better on a site dedicated to whatever programming language this is.

Comment: How exactly would t-test tell you anything about performance? It tests hypothesis about difference in means. Means of predictions could differ, but they could be equally wrong...

Comment: @Tim Yes. I want to find out two classification method is significantly different or not?

Comment: But it won't tell you that! It would tell you that the predictions on particular dataset differ. They may not differ, or differ differently on other dataset.

Comment: I think the fundamental issue here is one of statistics, not programming, so I am voting to leave it open.